# Локальный репозиторий для CentOS

Tags: centos, репозиторий

Встречаются вопросы о локальном репозитории, правда в основном для Debian/Ubuntu, поэтому хотел бы спросить, а для CentOS/Fedora/Red Hat методу кто знает?

Answer (score 1):

createrepo - создание локальных репозиториев в RH

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример: [HOWTO: Creating your own YUM RPM repository](http://blog.kagesenshi.org/2007/01/howto-creating-your-own-yum-rpm.html).